# Using list of strings to execute functions with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, namespaces

I would like to use a list object to call functions by name, passing arguments to each function, while list is used in a loop. *The functions have to be referenced as strings as in the actual scripts those are are sourced via command line input.*

## Functions

I've the following functions:

```
 def sum_a(x):
     x + 1000


 def sum_b(x):
     x + 100


 def sum_c(x):
     x + 1
```

## Calling

I would like to execute functions `sum_a` and `sum_c` for `x = 9`.

### Approach

```
functions_to_call = ['sum_a', 'sum_c']
x = 9
for each_call in functions_to_call:
    getattr(globals(), each_call)()
```

### Problem

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9f12b9113b60> in <module>()
      1 for each_call in functions_to_call:
----> 2     getattr(globals(), each_call)()
      3

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sum_a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to functions by their name. They behave just like variables.

```
functions_to_call = [sum_a, sum_c]
x = 9
for each_call in functions_to_call:
    each_call(x)
```

If you want to refer to the functions by name:

```
functions_to_call = ['sum_a', 'sum_c']
x = 9
for each_call in functions_to_call:
    globals()[each_call](x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to reference the functions directly:

```
functions_to_call = [sum_a, sum_c]
x = 9
for f in functions_to_call:
    f(x)
```

For your specific problem, `getattr` is searching for those attributes in the dictionary, but you want to access to the dictionary, for that you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> x = 10
>>> itemgetter("x")(globals())
10
```

A final version would look like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
functions_to_call = ['sum_a', 'sum_c']
x = 9
for each_call in map(itemgetter, functions_to_call):
    each_call(globals())(x)
```

Anyway, you should not use `globals` that way, is better to have an addressing dictionary:

```
funcs = {
    "sum_a" : sum_a,
    "sum_c" : sum_c
}
    functions_to_call = ['sum_a', 'sum_c']
    x = 9
    for each_call in functions_to_call:
        funcs.get(each_call, lambda *_: print("Selected function do not exist"))(x)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I want for the functions to be passed as strings as `['sum_a', 'sum_c']`. The reason being that this is a smaller part of bigger script that takes command line input of functions to execute. In effect, I'm looking for R's language equivalents to do `do.call` `call` `eval` and so on.